# Difference b/w Hill climbing and Beam search for #beam = 1

Tags: algorithm, search, beam-search

If we consider beam search with just 1 beam will be similar to hill climbing or is there some other difference? As per definition of beam search, it keeps track of k best states in a hill-climbing algorithm.so if k = 1, we should have a regular hill climber.

But i was asked the difference b/w them in a test so I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

I am on your side here - hill climbing **is** beam search with beam size 1.

Answer (score -1):

Beam search will not stuck in local max or local min position but hill climbing will stuck at local max or local min node